# How do I enter a string of 2 or more words in a Ruby word array shortcut?

Tags: ruby

I'm aware of the Ruby word array:

```
a = %w( stackoverflow serverfault superuser)
```

How can I use the above to display a list where each item can have 2 or more words, for instance:

```
a = ['stack overflow', 'server fault', 'super user']
```

Comment: All I know is you definitivelly will need a dictionary...
If it doesn't need to be quick, you can use the Google Search to grab it from the search results (the infamous Workaround Oriented Programming).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a = %w( stack\ overflow server\ fault super\ user)
```

Comment: Right, I didn't know you could do escaping in Ruby. I think I'll go with the more verbose way with the quotes.